# Google Cloud VPN: multiple tunnels from behind NAT

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform, ipsec

I would like to connect multiple separate NATted networks to a VPC Network using IPSec VPN. I do not fully understand the Google's documentation and I'm asking for some clarification here :) The doc is here: https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/resources/troubleshooting#gateways_behind_nat

My setup is like this:

```
| net1 | --- | router1 | --- \
                               \  priv        onprem       pub   
| net2 | --- | router2 | ----  | ---- | main_router NAT | ----------- >
                               /
| netN | --- | routerN | --- / 

    pub
> ----------- | Cloud VPN gateway(s) | --- | VPC Network |
```

I would like to have separate tunnels from each on-prem `routerN` to a Cloud VPC network, probably using `N` Cloud gateways. I do not fully understand if this is possible with the Cloud VPN. Could someone explain this a little? :)

```
router1 behind NAT <-- IPSec --> Cloud VPN gateway1
router2 behind NAT <-- IPSec --> Cloud VPN gateway2
...
```

Best Regards
Kamil

Answer (score 1):

I managed to run multiple tunnels from behind a single public IP address using one Cloud VPN per device behind NAT.

```
| net1 | --- | router1 | --- \
                               \  priv        onprem       pub   
| net2 | --- | router2 | ----  | ---- | main_router NAT | ----------- >
                               /
| netN | --- | routerN | --- / 

       /--> | Cloud VPN Gateway for router1 |
----> |--   | Cloud VPN Gateway for router2 |
       \--  | Cloud VPN Gateway for routerN |
```

Here is how:

- each device behind NAT initiating the IPSec tunnel (`router1`, `router2` `...` on the schema) should advertise its authentication id as the public IP of the NAT router (`main_router NAT`), **not** its private address.
- NAT router must allow ports 500 and 4500 from the Google Cloud VPN gateways.

**And now the most important part**: on the main NAT router set D-NAT rules that direct traffic from each Cloud VPN Gateway to the private IP of the device that established a specific tunnel. In other words, one have to set `N` `DNAT` rules for `N` tunnels. This way each initial `IKE` conversation from Cloud VPN can be delivered to the appropriate `routerN`. Each subsequent traffic is caputer under `ESTABLISHED,RELATED` stanzas.

I looked at rules counts, etc. on my routers and it works as I described above. The IPSec tunnel is a split tunnel, which means that the Cloud VPN Gateway will try to contact the address specified in the Gateway configuration -- which in our case is always the same public IP address of the `main_router NAT`. Our `main_router NAT` must forward packets (based on the source IP address) from specific Gateways to specific internal routers.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud VPN only supports one-to-one NAT via UDP encapsulation for NAT-Traversal (NAT-T).
One-to-many NAT and port-based address translation are not supported. In other words, Cloud VPN cannot connect to multiple on-premises or peer VPN gateways that share a single public IP address.

When using one-to-one NAT, an on-premises VPN gateway must be configured to identify itself using a public IP address, not its internal (private) address.

When you configure a Cloud VPN tunnel to connect to an on-premises VPN gateway, you specify an external IP address. Cloud VPN expects an on-premises VPN gateway to use its external IP address for its identity.
This is explained at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview?authuser=3&hl=vi#udp_and_nat) on Google's public documentation website.